# Searching dictionary prefixes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I am given:

`{"abc":2, "abcde":3, "aeg":1}` and a prefix in a function `prefixsearch(dictionary, prefix)`.

I need to search the dictionary using the prefix, i.e., "ab" will return me two entries

```
{"abc":2, "abcde":3}
```

I am struggling to code this using a normal for loop. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is `"abdce":2` coming from?

Comment: edited sorry @Austin

Comment: searching a dictionary by prefix worsens the lookp time - you need to iterate all keys, making int O(n) lookups instead of O(1).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
def prefixsearch(dictionary, prefix):
    return {k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k.startswith(prefix)}
```

---

```
d = {"abc":2, "abcde":3, "aeg":1}

prefixsearch(d, 'ab')
#{'abc': 2, 'abcde': 3}
```

---

Which would be equivalent to the following for loop:

```
def prefixsearch(dictionary, prefix):
    out = {}
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if k.startswith(prefix):
            out[k] = v
    return out
```

Comment: if i wanted to raise a keyError if there was no matching string then would I do this                                                                     with pytest.raises (KeyError) as e:
        len(out) = 0